# create NumberFormat without constructor

Tags: java, constructor, instantiation

I have the following class:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public static class NF
{
    public static NumberFormat formatShares = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    public static NumberFormat formatCash = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    public NF(){
        formatShares.setGroupingUsed(true);
        formatShares.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        formatCash.setGroupingUsed(true);
        formatCash.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        formatCash.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
   }       
}
```

Is there anyway to do this so I don't have to instantiate the class?  Essentially I want to be able to just use NF.formatCash.format(1234567.456)

Comment: Hint: use meaningful names for whatever you do. NF is a nothing telling name, and then both your formats should be **final**.

Comment: Thanks, NF ~ Number Format

Comment: I know. But in java, you avoid such abbreviations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your `NumberFormat` objects in a static initialization block:

```
public static class NF {
    public static NumberFormat formatShares = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    public static NumberFormat formatCash = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    static {
        formatShares.setGroupingUsed(true);
        formatShares.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        formatCash.setGroupingUsed(true);
        formatCash.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        formatCash.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
   }       
}
```

The code in the initialization block will run when the class is initialized, so no instance of `NF` will need to be created for your code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your class into a singleton.

It's not entirely the format you want but it does meet your requirements in that you do not have to instantiate the class yourself, it's done automatically when you want to use `NF`.

```
NF.getInstance().formatCash.format(1234567.456)
```

Your class would look like this then:

```
public class NF {
    public NumberFormat formatShares = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    public NumberFormat formatCash = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    private static NF theInstance;

    private NF() {
        formatShares.setGroupingUsed(true);
        formatShares.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        formatCash.setGroupingUsed(true);
        formatCash.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        formatCash.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    }

    public static NF getInstance() {
        if (theInstance == null) {
            theInstance = new NF();
        }
        return theInstance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is impossible. Directly or indirectly you create at least one `NumberFormat` instance. You can decrease amount of these instances.

*Using `static` object:*

```
public static final NumberFormat formatShares = NumberFormat.getInstance();

static {
    formatShares.setGroupingUsed(true);
    formatShares.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
}
```

This is not correct for multiple threads, because `NumberFormat` is not thread saved.

*Using `ThreadLocal` to use on instance per thread:*

```
public static final ThreadLocal<NumberFormat> threadLocalFormatShares = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setGroupingUsed(true);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
    return nf;
});

NumberFormat formatShares = threadLocalFormatShares.get();
```

I think this could solve your problem.